# How to get value from the invalid JSON

Tags: php, jquery

I have a URL who returns the JSON response but the response is not proper for description element and I want to retrieve price from the description element.

Here is the URL: https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/details?product_id=67462&sort=newest&source=react

Here is the JSON response:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "response": {
    "id": "67462",
    "offers": [],
    "rating": 4.4,
    "is_saleable": true,
    "is_backorder": 0,
    "name": "Indulekha Bringha Hair Oil Selfie Bottle (Pack Of 2) (100ml)",
    "sku": "NYINDUCOM0001",
    "image_url": "https://adn-static1.nykaa.com/media/catalog/product/cache/3/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/n/y/nyinducom0001.jpg",
    "pack_size": null,
    "type": "bundle",
    "fbn": "0",
    "promo": null,
    "slug": "indulekha-bringha-hair-oil-selfie-bottle-pack-of-2.html",
    "all_images": {
      "0": "https://adn-static1.nykaa.com/media/catalog/product/cache/3/image/800x800/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/n/y/nyinducom0001.jpg"
    },
    "use": "",
    "description": "Indulekha Bringha Hair Oil: (MRP: 432.00/-) | Quantity: 2</font></strong>\r\nIndulekha Bringha Oil is an Ayurvedic proprietary medicine recommended for the regulation of hair and scalp conditions like hairfall, dandruff etc. The excellent action of Indulekha Bringha oil is due to the actions of its ingredients and the special manufacturing procedure of the base oil.During the production of Indulekha Bringha Oil, the Swethakutaja leaves are dipped in pure coconut milk oil (prepared by cold process technology). This prolonged blending process helps to extract the entire medicinal quality of the leaves and thus makes it an effective ingredient of Indulekha Bringha Oil.Active ingredients along with the base oil create an excellent combination that is extremely beneficial for hair.• SvethakutajaIt has anti-inflammatory and anti-dandruff properties. Also known for its antimicrobial properties and hence used for all types of psoriasis (skin disorder) and dandruff.• Aloe veraAloe vera contains enzymes which repairs dead skin cells on the scalp. It promotes hair growth, prevents itching on the scalp, reduces dandruff and conditions your hair. it rejuvenates the hair with its own nutrients, giving it more elasticity and preventing breakage.\"• NeemProvides anti-protozoal, antioxidant, anti-inflammatory and antibacterial properties. Neem helps to treat these conditions of hair and cleanse the scalp for healthy hair growth.• BringharajHelps to improve hair growth and colour. Its extracts rejuvenates hair keeping the hair lustrous, dark and healthy. It also helps to nurture and condition hair.• AmlaRichest source of Vitamin C & antioxidants. It helps maintain youthful hair color and retards premature graying and supports the strength of the hair follicles.• Virgin Coconut OilVirgin coconut oil is extracted by the cold compression method. It is higher in vitamin content, antioxidants, minerals, fragrance and even the amount of protein.</p>\r\n\r\nKey Features & Benefits : </b></p>\r\n\r\nContains ingredient known to grow hair</li>\r\nContains ingredient known to Nourishes the Scalp</li>\r\nContains ingredient known to reduce dandruff</li>\r\nSelfie bottle massgaes the scalp</li>\r\nApplicator Reduces wastage of oil</li></ul>\r\n\r\n",
    "ingredients": "",
    "user_rating": 0,
    "review_count": "37",
    "delivery_description": "\r\nFree Shipping</b></p>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nAbove Rs. 500</p>\r\n\r\n\r\nDispatched in 3 business days</p>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nFree Cash on Delivery</b></p>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nAbove Rs.500</p>\r\n\r\n\r\nTo selected pincodes</p>",
    "top_review": [
      {
        "created_at": "2016-11-17 09:46:37",
        "title": "no more hair loss",
        "detail": "I have been using this product for 6 months now and have experienced excellent results. My hair loss was stopped within few weeks and it helped to increase my hair volume too. I have started recommending this product to family and friends now.",
        "nickname": "Ratnavali Kalse",
        "value": "5",
        "likes": "10"
      }
    ],
    "review_splitup": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "count": "7",
        "per": 1.5418502202643
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "count": "5",
        "per": 1.1013215859031
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "count": "44",
        "per": 9.6916299559471
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "count": "128",
        "per": 28.193832599119
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "count": "270",
        "per": 59.471365638767
      }
    ],
    "button_text": "ADD TO BAG",
    "show_pincode_check": "1",
    "rating_count": 454,
    "category_ids": "24,25,26,175,214,540,547,569,1145,1214,1266,1284,1380,1382,1391,1396,1414,2039,2040,2058,2117,2150,2153,2204,3584,3843,3892,3894,4006,4147,4481,4545,4598,4608,4610,5744,6210,6248,6309,6367,6524,6872,6912",
    "brand_ids": "2673",
    "delivery_status": "2",
    "product_type": "jit",
    "is_lux": 0,
    "tryItOn": 0,
    "object_type": "product",
    "price": 864,
    "final_price": 778,
    "discount": 10,
    "show_wishlist_button": 0,
    "enable_dynamiccombo": 0,
    "enable_customers_alsoviewed": 0,
    "enable_customers_alsoviewed_barriliance": 0,
    "device_ip": "180.233.120.244",
    "show_stock_status": 0
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

Comment: Provide more info, what value do you want to get?

Comment: If the JSON formatting is invalid you cannot parse it, so getting the value is not easy. You'd probably have to end up using some Regex to get the key you need and the associated value. A much better idea would be to fix the response, or request for it to be fixed by the API provider

Comment: @bored_lines  OP says correctly:- `I want to retrieve price from the description element.`. BTW agreed with RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I tried `json_decode` the data from the URL you provided and works just fine. I was able to get the price like `$json['response']['price']`

Comment: Eddie is right, what the URL actually returns seems to be perfectly valid JSON - in contrast to what you have copy&pasted into the question. So you need to go figure out at which point you messed the data up while you were handling it ...

Comment: Just formatted the JSON on https://jsoneditoronline.org/ to make us see all better.

Comment: I actually want to get the Price value from the description element which is mentioned in the JSON return please see this URL: https://www.nykaa.com/app-api/index.php/products/details?product_id=67462&sort=newest&source=react

Comment: Thanks, Everyone for great help issue has been resolved now.

Comment: This link has wrong content-type, the right content-type is application/json.